# Is \u the only way to output the user from .bashrc?

Tags: bash, macos

I can't get it to work on my Mac (catalina version 10.15.2).
`\u` works on ubuntu when I test it but not on my Mac. 
I want to customize my mac terminal. Colors work fine on my Mac and it's reading the `.bashrc` file when I test it by `source .bashrc`  .
For example with the following in `.bashrc` in the user home directory.

```
orange=$(tput setaf 166);
PS1="${orange}\u"
export PS1;
```

Outputs my username in orange on ubuntu but on my Mac it just outputs `\u` in orange so for some reason `\u` isn't working on my Mac? Is there an alternative I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the release of macOS Catalina (10.15) Apple has switched to Zsh as default shell (instead of Bash).
Instead of setting *PS1* in Bash you can set *PROMPT* in Zsh:
`PROMPT="${orange}%n"`

Comment: It is too bad this was hastened by fear of GPL3 versions of bash.  https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh/